# How to display Date Icon Message(click to open date calender) tooltip

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, tooltip

I need to display the message if i bring cursor near to calender icon as **Click to open calender** but now it say like in the image.

[image]

I m using JQuery and JavaScript in my project.

Here is my code for datepicker:

```
$( ".date" ).datepicker({"dateFormat": "yy-mm-dd",   showOn: "button",
        buttonImage: "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/images/icon_cal.png",
        buttonImageOnly: true, title:"Click to open date calender" });
```

Comment: i think use of tooltip will be useful,and remove java tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's hard to help you with this issue when there is no source code or a link to view. you issue could me many things:

1.) is the style rule for the cursor hand overwritten by another css rule?
2.) did you forget to define the "title" attribute for the icon?

if i had to guess, it would be option 2.  i say this because the jquery ui datepicker demo has the same behavior.  if you go here: http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#icon-trigger
you will see the icon has the same output you have in your image.  then if you look at the source for the datepicker demo, you'll see:

that is probably your issue.

Comment: Please check my edited question code, Now i given Title attribute.But it loads the same

Answer (score 1):

Use the standard HTML title attribute of image:-

```
<img src="source of image" alt="alternative text" title="this will be displayed as a tooltip"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

To change the text on button image you need to set the "buttonText" attribute, e.g.

```
$("#my_date_field").datepicker({
  showOn: "button",
  buttonImage: "/images/calendar.png",
  buttonImageOnly: true,
  buttonText: "Add some new text"
});
```